# How to seperate two differently named text files from a folder. Is there any classifier that do directly based on title given to file

Tags: python, nlp

I had a folder as employment in which i had 1500 files of two different types like aggrement and amendment. my task is to build a classifier that seperates two different files and put in the two different folder.

Comment: And the distinguishing features between `agreement` and `amendment` are… ?

Comment: yes i need to distinguish based on features between agreement and amendment.